# Trying to observe javascript Object

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern, callstack

I'm trying to create an object observer in javascript.

This is as far as i get:

```
//object to observe an object
        observe : {
            parent : this, //keep context of parent
            references : {}, //keep track of setted references
            originals : {}, // also for the originals
            callStack : 0, // trying to prevent the callstack

            // set an object to observe..
            setObject : function ( name, object ){
                this.references[name] = object;
                //app.utils.extendObject is a working object extending function.
                this.originals[name] = app.utils.extendObject( new Object , object );
                //start watching the object
                this.watchObject( name );
            },

            watchObject : function ( referenceName ){
                this.callStack++;
                //walk through reference
                for( prop in this.references[referenceName] ){
                    // if the reference differs from the original...
                    if( this.references[referenceName][prop] !== this.originals[referenceName][prop]  ){
                        //... log the differance
                        console.log( referenceName + " with property " + prop + " has changed." );
                    }
                }
                // set variable with call to this function
                var func = eval( "app.utils.observe.watchObject(" + referenceName + ")" );

                //read somewhere this could do the trick
                if( callStack == 1000 ){
                    setTimeout( func , 100 );
                }
                func();

            }

        }
```

The problem is the callstack error, is there a better way to observe this?
Ofcourse I could use Object.observe currently in Chrome but I want a crossbrowser solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit, added `callback` function to `watchObject` method. It's usefull if you want to listen changes and perform some actions.

```
watchObject: function (referenceName, callback) {
    for (prop in this.references[referenceName]) {
        if (this.references[referenceName][prop] !== this.originals[referenceName][prop]) {
            console.log(referenceName + " with property " + prop + " has changed.");
            callback && callback.call(this.references[referenceName], this.originals[referenceName][prop], this.references[referenceName][prop]);
            this.originals[referenceName][prop] = this.references[referenceName][prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Plus I placed `setInterval` in the `setObject`:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function() {
    self.watchObject(name, callback);
}, 300);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59Fnt/1/

Comment: HEy thanks for your quick respond!
What is this bind function doing exactly? 

Also like some explanation on the callback && callback line.  

I see that it works, which is great!

Comment: I also get the callback line now. Your checking if the callback exists and then call the callback with its context and params. THANKS

But why itsn't this giving me a callstack error?

Comment: Right, if you provide callback it will be invoked with the old and new values. I'm not sure about callstack error though.